# Is this a memory address?

Tags: memory, gdb

I am learning gdb, and I got my first error. This was the error:

```
0x00007fff83074096 in __kill ()
```

Is the address:

```
0x00007fff83074096
```

... a memory address in Hex format? I've converted it to decimal, out of interest, and the number is huge. I fail to believe that so many memory addresses exist.

Comment: ...are you running it in 64-bit mode?

Comment: Why -1? It was a genuine question. I am on a computer science course and just learning. I have seen memory addresses in hexadecimal but no where near that big, which is why I asked about its format.

Comment: @Matti I am running a new Macbook Pro. I think its 64 bit yes.

Comment: @Stacey Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Comment: Interesting how people ask whether the system is 64-bit, when clearly the address exceeds 32 bit capacity ...

Comment: Dont worry about the -1, there are many trolls under these bridges.  They like to come out and give -1 then go back in without giving any valuable input to the community.  It makes them feel big.

Comment: @sehe: My question was more or less rhetoric.

Comment: @Matti: ok, I see what you were aiming for then :)

Comment: I downvoted this, because a tiny bit of critical thought would have obviated the need for this question, and it doesn't really add to the quality of the answer base.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running on a 64-bit platform, then yes, addresses that large exist.  (See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address.)

Of course, it's possible that you simply have a buffer overflow somewhere, which has corrupted your stack, and overwritten the address with nonsense.

Comment: Buffer overflow clearly has noting to do with this -- GDB resolved the address to __kill.

Comment: @Employed: And how do you know that a buffer overflow has not overwritten the return address on the stack, and that we've not been randomly thrown into this function?

Comment: I know that because the the crash address is not (usually) located on stack -- it comes directly from the kernel. When you see a stack corruption, you always get correct crash point (on every UNIX system I've seen in the last 15 years). You just don't see the rest of the call stack. Try a test case that corrupts stack and see for yourself. Here is one to save you typing: void foo() { char buf[1], *p = buf; while (p) { *p++ = 'a'; } }
int main() { foo(); return 0; }

Answer (score 5):

Yup. It is.

It is an address in a 64 bit process's virtual memory space.

Not all of the addresses are in use (that's what an address is: it is a label only).

You can see more about the address by doing

```
:break 0x00007fff83074096
:list 0x00007fff83074096
:disassemble 0x00007fff83074096
```

See the whole of the stack bactkrace

```
 :bt full
```

In all threads

```
 :thread apply all bt full
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a memory address. Due to [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), there are vastly more memory addresses available than actual memory to *back* the virtual address space.

You might find running `pmap -x 1` or `pmap -x $$` instructive, along with looking at `/proc/pid/maps` contents for different processes. (`cat /proc/self/maps` is easy to run.)

Answer (score 2):

16 hex digits x 4 (bits represented by one hex digit) = 64 bits. You're using a 64 bit platform, why are you surprised?